# systemd: cgroups: BlockIOWeight or IOWeight

Tags: systemd, cgroups

I want to set  block I/O weight for one of my services. Should I use BlockIOWeight or IOWeight?

Do I need to add `BlockIOAccounting=yes` or `IOAccounting=yes`?

```
~/ mount
...
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
```